# Post hoc tests for permutation repeated measure anova

Tags: permutation, anova, posthoc

I have a two-way designed experiment, which are two species and three treatments(n = 5 or 6, for each group), and I measure leaf area every three months of same individuals (repeated measured).

Because my data is heterogeneous variance (tested with levene test) and the sample size is small, I decide to use permutation.

Here is my script. I used **aovperm()** to build the model, and set Error(number/(month)) as random factor (number is the ID of individuals).

```
area.aovp<-aovperm(p_area~species*treatment*month + Error(number/(month)), data = growth, type = "permutation", np = 2000, method = "Rd_kheradPajouh_renaud")
```

For doing post-hoc tests, I've tryed **lsmeans()** and **glht()**, but neither of them could work with the  permutated anova.

Is there other proper way to do such post hoc?

Comment: It ma be possible to do it using emmeans::qdrg, if aovperm provides estimates of the means and covariance matrix of those estimates.

Comment: I looked at this briefly and it looks like we're close, but missing the `vcov()` result we need. I wrote the developer of **permuco**. BTW, it would be really helpful in questions like this if you would mention what R package(s) you are using.

Comment: Hi Lenth, thank you for your reply! I use permuco::aovperm to do the permutation ancova. Now I'm trying bootstrap to get the emmeans and also the paircomparison. It looks right for now!

Comment: I heard back from the permuco developer. Unfortunately, those methods do NOT fit well into the emmeans framework.

Comment: You might want to look at my [answer to another recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/586936/bootstrap-anova-and-posthoc-comparisons-for-non-normal-data/587024#587024) with an example of getting bootstrap results into emmeans.